# Help lighting LED via GPIO pins

Tags: python, led

So I got an RPi and a canakit, I'm trying to follow a guide to get a simple program to make the LED blink. I have very little experience with RPis so it's probably a very simple error, but I can't figure out why it won't work. When I run the program I get a runtime error. I will post pictures of my wiring as well as the code. Thanks!

Wiring: [image: http://i.imgur.com/RYv8lcW.jpg]

Code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
#blink function
def blink(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
    return
#Use raspberry pi board numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#GPIO output channel
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

for i in range(0,50):
    blink(11)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Once you have reached a small amount of reputation (10, I believe) you can also include images as well (by using the picture icon in the top-bar of the edit frame) - as you have not quite got that I have done that for you.

Comment: `GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)` <- `pin` is not defined here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your script, you have:

> ```
> GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
> ```

and then you call `blink(11)`, which will lead to calling:

> ```
> GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
> ```

That is, the pin numbers don't match. You want to change both to 7 or both to 11.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def blink(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

pin = 7
blink(pin)
```

Comment: Lol wow, I figured it was something simple, but not that obvious. Thanks a bunch!